# Chrome disables WebGL 2.0 after I it was working before

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, updates, intel-graphics, blacklist

I have a Dell Vostro with Intel HD Graphics 3000,

I use this computer from time to time when I don't have aceess to my main laptop (an HP with AMD radeon),

But today I was chocked when a toy webgl 2 project I tried to run, which was working 2 or 3 months ago could not get a webgl2 context.

I spend the whole day investigating everything.

I checked if my driver got updated with windows, ... no, can I update it ? no update available.

Which leads me to think that chrome blacklisted this device in the span of time that I stopped using this laptop (if so ... why ?, and how can I revert it, webgl2 used to work fine, at least for the subset I was using [vao, samplers, uniform objects, glsl es 3.0])

Here is the `chrome://gpu` report

```
Graphics Feature Status

Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Metal: Disabled
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Skia Renderer: Disabled
Surface Control: Disabled
Surface Synchronization: Enabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Viz Service Display Compositor: Enabled
Viz Hit-test Surface Layer: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Unavailable

Driver Bug Workarounds

clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
disable_accelerated_vpx_decode
disable_d3d11
disable_direct_composition
disable_discard_framebuffer
disable_larger_than_screen_overlays
disable_nv12_dynamic_textures
exit_on_context_lost
force_cube_complete
msaa_is_slow
scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent

Problems Detected

Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process sandbox
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
Old Intel drivers cannot reliably support D3D11: 363721
Applied Workarounds: disable_d3d11
ANGLE crash on glReadPixels from incomplete cube map texture: 518889
Applied Workarounds: force_cube_complete
On Intel GPUs MSAA performance is not acceptable for GPU rasterization: 527565
Applied Workarounds: msaa_is_slow
Framebuffer discarding can hurt performance on non-tilers: 570897
Applied Workarounds: disable_discard_framebuffer
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Decode and Encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures on Windows: 634519
Applied Workarounds: decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
Accelerated VPx decoding is hanging on some videos.: 654111
Applied Workarounds: disable_accelerated_vpx_decode
Overlay sizes bigger than screen aren't accelerated on some Intel drivers: 720059
Applied Workarounds: disable_larger_than_screen_overlays
Direct composition causes rendering issues on Intel SandyBridge and IvyBridge GPUs: 775898, 785648, 9245627
Applied Workarounds: disable_direct_composition
Dynamic texture map crashes on Intel drivers less than version 24: 890227
Applied Workarounds: disable_nv12_dynamic_textures
Metal is only available on macOS.
Disabled Features: metal
Viz hit-test surface layer version is not enabled by default.
Disabled Features: viz_hit_test_surface_layer
Skia renderer is not used by default.
Disabled Features: skia_renderer

Version Information

Data exported   2019-09-23T10:38:28.042Z
Chrome version  Chrome/76.0.3809.132
Operating system    Windows NT 10.0.17763
Software rendering list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/fd1acc410994a7a68ac25bc77513d443f3130860/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json
Driver bug list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/fd1acc410994a7a68ac25bc77513d443f3130860/gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_list.json
ANGLE commit id 9379eed38531
2D graphics backend Skia/76 f13f8690bede09ca97071e9786d68bc0758a24cc
Command Line    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --ignore-gpu-blacklist --flag-switches-end
Driver Information
Initialization time 250
In-process GPU  false
Passthrough Command Decoder true
Sandboxed   true
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x8086 [Google Inc.], DEVICE= 0x0116 [ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 Direct3D9Ex vs_3_0 ps_3_0)] *ACTIVE*
Optimus false
AMD switchable  false
Desktop compositing Aero Glass
Direct composition  false
Supports overlays   false
YUY2 overlay support    NONE
NV12 overlay support    NONE
Diagonal Monitor Size of \\.\DISPLAY1   15.5"
Driver D3D12 feature level  Not supported
Driver Vulkan API version   Not supported
Driver vendor   Intel Corporation
Driver version  9.17.10.4459
Driver date 5-19-2016
GPU CUDA compute capability major version   0
Pixel shader version    3.0
Vertex shader version   3.0
Max. MSAA samples   4
Machine model name  
Machine model version   
GL_VENDOR   Google Inc.
GL_RENDERER ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 Direct3D9Ex vs_3_0 ps_3_0)
GL_VERSION  OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.9379eed38531)
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_ANGLE_client_arrays GL_ANGLE_depth_texture GL_ANGLE_explicit_context GL_ANGLE_explicit_context_gles1 GL_ANGLE_framebuffer_blit GL_ANGLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_ANGLE_instanced_arrays GL_ANGLE_memory_size GL_ANGLE_multi_draw GL_ANGLE_pack_reverse_row_order GL_ANGLE_program_cache_control GL_ANGLE_request_extension GL_ANGLE_robust_client_memory GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ANGLE_texture_usage GL_ANGLE_translated_shader_source GL_CHROMIUM_bind_generates_resource GL_CHROMIUM_bind_uniform_location GL_CHROMIUM_color_buffer_float_rgb GL_CHROMIUM_color_buffer_float_rgba GL_CHROMIUM_copy_texture GL_CHROMIUM_lose_context GL_CHROMIUM_sync_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_NV_fence GL_NV_pack_subimage GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_array_object
Disabled Extensions GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Disabled WebGL Extensions   
Window system binding vendor    Google Inc. (adapter LUID: 0000000000009271)
Window system binding version   1.4 (ANGLE 2.1.0.9379eed38531)
Window system binding extensions    EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_ANGLE_d3d_share_handle_client_buffer EGL_ANGLE_d3d_texture_client_buffer EGL_ANGLE_surface_d3d_texture_2d_share_handle EGL_ANGLE_query_surface_pointer EGL_ANGLE_window_fixed_size EGL_NV_post_sub_buffer EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_EXT_device_query EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANGLE_flexible_surface_compatibility EGL_ANGLE_create_context_webgl_compatibility EGL_CHROMIUM_create_context_bind_generates_resource EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_ANGLE_display_texture_share_group EGL_ANGLE_create_context_client_arrays EGL_ANGLE_program_cache_control EGL_ANGLE_robust_resource_initialization EGL_ANGLE_create_context_extensions_enabled EGL_ANDROID_blob_cache EGL_ANDROID_recordable EGL_ANGLE_workaround_control
Direct rendering version    unknown
Reset notification strategy 0x8252
GPU process crash count 0
gfx::BufferFormats supported for allocation and texturing   R_8: not supported, R_16: not supported, RG_88: not supported, BGR_565: not supported, RGBA_4444: not supported, RGBX_8888: not supported, RGBA_8888: not supported, BGRX_8888: not supported, BGRX_1010102: not supported, RGBX_1010102: not supported, BGRA_8888: not supported, RGBA_F16: not supported, YVU_420: not supported, YUV_420_BIPLANAR: not supported, UYVY_422: not supported
Compositor Information
Tile Update Mode    One-copy
Partial Raster  Enabled
GpuMemoryBuffers Status
R_8 Software only
R_16    Software only
RG_88   Software only
BGR_565 Software only
RGBA_4444   Software only
RGBX_8888   GPU_READ, SCANOUT
RGBA_8888   GPU_READ, SCANOUT
BGRX_8888   Software only
BGRX_1010102    Software only
RGBX_1010102    Software only
BGRA_8888   Software only
RGBA_F16    Software only
YVU_420 Software only
YUV_420_BIPLANAR    Software only
UYVY_422    Software only
Display(s) Information
Info    Display[2528732444] bounds=[0,0 1366x768], workarea=[0,30 1366x738], scale=1, external.
Color space information {primaries:BT709, transfer:IEC61966_2_1, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}
Bits per color component    8
Bits per pixel  24
Refresh Rate in Hz  60
Video Acceleration Information
Decode h264 baseline    up to 1920x1088 pixels
Decode h264 main    up to 1920x1088 pixels
Decode h264 high    up to 1920x1088 pixels
Encode h264 baseline    up to 3840x2176 pixels and/or 30.000 fps
Encode h264 main    up to 3840x2176 pixels and/or 30.000 fps
Encode h264 high    up to 3840x2176 pixels and/or 30.000 fps
Diagnostics
0
b3DAccelerationEnabled  true
b3DAccelerationExists   true
bAGPEnabled true
bAGPExistenceValid  true
bAGPExists  true
bCanRenderWindow    true
bDDAccelerationEnabled  true
bDriverBeta false
bDriverDebug    false
bDriverSigned   false
bDriverSignedValid  false
bNoHardware false
dwBpp   32
dwDDIVersion    11
dwHeight    768
dwRefreshRate   60
dwWHQLLevel 0
dwWidth 1366
iAdapter    0
lDriverSize 12935296
lMiniVddSize    0
szAGPStatusEnglish  Enabled
szAGPStatusLocalized    Enabled
szChipType  Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
szD3DStatusEnglish  Enabled
szD3DStatusLocalized    Enabled
szDACType   Internal
szDDIVersionEnglish 11.1
szDDIVersionLocalized   11.1
szDDStatusEnglish   Enabled
szDDStatusLocalized Enabled
szDXVAHDEnglish Supported
szDXVAModes ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C ModeWMV9_C ModeVC1_C
szDescription   Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
szDeviceId  0x0116
szDeviceIdentifier  {D7B78E66-4256-11CF-F362-9D25B7C2C435}
szDeviceName    \\.\DISPLAY1
szDisplayMemoryEnglish  1664 MB
szDisplayMemoryLocalized    1664 MB
szDisplayModeEnglish    1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
szDisplayModeLocalized  1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
szDriverAssemblyVersion 9.17.10.4459
szDriverAttributes  Final Retail
szDriverDateEnglish 5/19/2016 1:00:00 AM
szDriverDateLocalized   5/19/2016 01:00:00
szDriverLanguageEnglish English
szDriverLanguageLocalized   English
szDriverModelEnglish    WDDM 1.2
szDriverModelLocalized  WDDM 1.2
szDriverName    igdumd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll
szDriverNodeStrongName  oem6.inf:5f63e534c4a6341c:iSNBM0:9.17.10.4459:pci\ven_8086&dev_0116
szDriverSignDate    Unknown
szDriverVersion 9.17.0010.4459
szKeyDeviceID   Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0116&SUBSYS_05971028&REV_09
szKeyDeviceKey  \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{93AA93C5-570B-11E9-8A28-EDA09E932711}\0000
szManufacturer  Intel Corporation
szMiniVdd   unknown
szMiniVddDateEnglish    Unknown
szMiniVddDateLocalized  unknown
szMonitorMaxRes Unknown
szMonitorName   Generic PnP Monitor
szNotesEnglish  No problems found.
szNotesLocalized    No problems found.
szOverlayEnglish    Supported
szRankOfInstalledDriver 00D12001
szRegHelpText   Unknown
szRevision  Unknown
szRevisionId    0x0009
szSubSysId  0x05971028
szTestResultD3D7English Not run
szTestResultD3D7Localized   Not run
szTestResultD3D8English Not run
szTestResultD3D8Localized   Not run
szTestResultD3D9English Not run
szTestResultD3D9Localized   Not run
szTestResultDDEnglish   Not run
szTestResultDDLocalized Not run
szVdd   unknown
szVendorId  0x8086
Log Messages
GpuProcessHostUIShim:
GpuProcessHostUIShim:
```

Comment: I installed firefox and webgl 2.0 is working fine. chrome is weird, and I hate it now.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Finally found a workaround thanks to this [website](https://www.cadcam-e.com/EnSuite-Web/Diagnostics/#DriverBugsWorkaround)

use `--disable_d3d11=0` when starting Chrome, for example my shortcut now is:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable_d3d11=0`

---

Have this issue as well, the "official" reason as seen in [this file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/79.0.3945.95/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json) is:

```
{
  "id": 112,
  "description": "Intel HD 3000 driver crashes frequently on Mac",
  "cr_bugs": [592130, 661596],
  "os": {
    "type": "macosx"
  },
  "vendor_id": "0x8086",
  "device_id": ["0x0116", "0x0126"],
  "multi_gpu_category": "any",
  "features": [
    "all"
  ]
}
```

But it specifically list only `macosx` so no clue why it is blocked on windows... really annoying.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me. On Windows 7 with Intel hd 3000 graphics (Lenovo T420) i was able to enable WebGL2

Comment: thanks this worked

Answer (score 0):

sorry to let you know this if it shows

```
WebGL2: Unavailable
```

Then WebGL is not available in hardware or software.
I have the same problem and I checked out a website which said [Check out this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn7Nx.png)

This is the link of the the website  https://wevideo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/225259448-How-to-enable-WebGL